# OpenGL does not recognize #version directive

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I'm having issues with my GLSL version, upon running my program I receive a warning saying:

> WARNING: 0:29: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for
>   float

which is very strange to me, because both of my shaders specify `#version 330 core` for example my vertex.vert

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 squareVertices;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 xyzs; // Position of the center of the particule and size of the square
layout(location = 2) in vec4 color; // Position of the center of the particule and size of the square

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec2 UV;
out vec4 particlecolor;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform vec3 CameraRight_worldspace;
uniform vec3 CameraUp_worldspace;
uniform mat4 VP; // Model-View-Projection matrix, but without the Model (the position is in BillboardPos; the orientation depends on the camera)

void main()
{
    float particleSize = xyzs.w; // because we encoded it this way.
    vec3 particleCenter_wordspace = xyzs.xyz;

    vec3 vertexPosition_worldspace = 
        particleCenter_wordspace
        + CameraRight_worldspace * squareVertices.x * particleSize
        + CameraUp_worldspace * squareVertices.y * particleSize;

    // Output position of the vertex
    gl_Position = VP * vec4(vertexPosition_worldspace, 1.0f);

    // UV of the vertex. No special space for this one.
    UV = squareVertices.xy + vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    particlecolor = color;
}
```

Creating the window in SFML

```
sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800,600),   //declare window
        "Particle Simulation"                   //window title
        );                                      //default context settings
```

is something wrong with my shader? Or would it be a problem with how I read my shader in?

Comment: Do you actually have OpenGL 3.3, and are you setting up your context as 3.3?

Comment: @mclaassen my OpenGL supports up to 4.0, and I'm actually not sure on context, could you expand?

Comment: @Gmercer015 Show the code where you set up the GL context. (e.g. open the window etc.)

Comment: Dpeending on whether you're using GLUT or GLEW you would have something like 'glutInitContextVersion (3,3);'

Comment: @mclaassen looks like I need to look into the default SFML context settings, most likely solved this problem. If you want to make an answer I'd be happy to accept

Comment: That warning nakes no sense, the `f` precision suffix was added in GLSL 1.20. It should say "only GLSL versions 120 or newer", ***not*** "only version 110".

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman it most likely means versions GREATER('>') than 110

Comment: @Gmercer015 I thought that too, but the singular grammar makes it confusing to me :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the actual OpenGL context is being initialized with the correct version. If you are initializing the context with an older version then it doesn't matter what the shader says it supports.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the GL context version when creating the context.

In case of SFML it would look like the following:

```
sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "OpenGL", 
    sf::Style::Default, sf::ContextSettings(32, 8, 0, 3, 3));
```

[Documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/structsf_1_1ContextSettings.php#details)

SFML defaults to a 2.0 context if no other is specified.